# no style changes without "!important" in media queries

Tags: sass

Error with scss code, can't style anything in media queries without "!important". What could be wrong and also everytime  I save any scss file other than main.scss it causes an error but when I save the main.scss file then it works fine. Any suggestions? I'm using webpack.

```
 .loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    .logo {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 8em) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .logo {
        width: 60% !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .logo {
        width: 40% !important;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .logo {
        width: 20% !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using .logo inside .loading

try to do it like this

```
.loading {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo {
    width: 80%;
}
```

This way you should be able to use the media queries without `!important`.

The nested way has higher complexity than the media query so that's why you had to use `!important`.

Comment: Works thanks! So why use scss and nesting if it causes media query issues? Weird right?

Comment: @harpreet
 You can also use it like:
`.logo {
    width: 80%;
    @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

or 

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .loading {
        .logo{
            width: 40%;
        }
    }
}` if you want to nest the `.logo`

Comment: oh put the media query into the.logo itself?

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/write-media-queries-sass Maybe this can help you better understand what you can do. Hope it helps you :)